# ElementNotInteractable Exception: Message: Element <a href=> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click and download "Real Sector" on the following link:
http://www.sbp.org.pk/reports/quarterly/fy19/Second/qtr-index-eng.htm

Here is what I have tried:

```
driver.get('http://www.sbp.org.pk/reports/quarterly/fy19/Second/qtr-index-eng.htm')
try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href= 'Chap-2.pdf']").click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

But it gives following error:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply Explicit Wait and wait till the element is present on the page and then you can click on it.
**You can also scroll to the element first and then click on it.**
You can do it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get('http://www.sbp.org.pk/reports/quarterly/fy19/Second/qtr-index-eng.htm')
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='Chap-2.pdf']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

**OR**

You can directly click on the element using java script click like:

```
driver.get('http://www.sbp.org.pk/reports/quarterly/fy19/Second/qtr-index-eng.htm')
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='Chap-2.pdf']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Comment: @Muhammadhassan have edited my ans, please pick the updated ans.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan Strange because it is working fine for me. I have added an alternate approach to click on the element(using javascript click). Please check that and use that and please check the xpath that i have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks man, the second solution worked as expected. However, I am still unable to understand why the first solution worked for you and didn't worked for me.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan might be because the size of chrome you have opened is different from mine, it might work when you maximise the chrome and then try to click on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait use `element_to_be_clickable`

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href= 'Chap-2.pdf']")))
element.click()
```

Comment: @Muhammadhassan I've updated the code with `WebDriverWait`, please try again

Answer (score 0):

To click on `"Real Sector"` link Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath` option.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.sbp.org.pk/reports/quarterly/fy19/Second/qtr-index-eng.htm')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'Real Sector')]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Browser snapshot** after clicking.

[image]